# Updating leads without an id in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am new to apex development and I have a requirement where I need to update leads with a first and last name. There are no other ids. Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: If you only have the names to go on, how will you handle real and false duplicates ? (There may be 2 persons with the name John Doe, living at different adresses, being 2 different humans - who will you update ?).

Comment: The business wants to take a chance and just get them updated. They do not have any other option. There could be huge possibilities of dups

Answer (score 1):

What is update context?

You can update records in Salesforce from several context:

- Apex Trigger
- Async Apex job
- VisualForce pages

In different context the way for obtaining records may be different, but generally you need to query records using [SOQL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index_Left.htm). It's hard to provide a good example without full requirements for your code, so it'll be something like that

```apex
Set<String> setOfNames = new Set<String>();
setOfNames.add('Tom James');
setOfNames.add('Shelly Brownell');
setOfNames.add('Bertha Boxer');
List<Lead> leadsForUpdate = [SELECT Id, fieldForUpdate__c
                             FROM Lead
                             WHERE Name IN: setOfNames];
```

criteria for SOQL query might be formed in any other way which meets your requirements

Comment: Hi Pavel. thanks for getting back to me. There are leads in the systems where the lead source needs to be updated so that they can send out emails for the 2014 conferences. they have given me a set of 1450 records with names and address information but no emails. so i need to match the first and last names with the ones already existing in the lead object and then update the lead source to 2014 conference